# vue js don't update the model

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i have a strange behavior on vuejs (version 2):

i have a method which update a model data, this method named "AddServizi
", is triggered using v-on:click and it work perfectly:

HTML

```
                        <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    v-bind:id="['gialla-'+index]"
                    name="serviziGialla" 
                    v-bind:value="servizio.nomeServizio"
                    v-model="giallaPicked"
                    v-on:click="AddServizi(servizio.selected,servizio.classe,servizio.nomeServizio,servizio.descrizione,servizio.descrizione_lunga,index,servizio.x,servizio.y)"/>
                    <label 
                    v-bind:for="['gialla-'+index]"
                    ><span></span>
                    </label>
```

JS

```
    AddServizi: function(selected,classe,nomeServizio,descriziones,descrizione_lungas,index,x,y){
    $("#sottoSelezionati").removeClass("in");
    this.servizi_selezionati.splice(0);
    if(selected==null){selected=false};
    if(!selected){
        this.servizi_selezionati.push({
            lineaApparte:classe,
            servizio:nomeServizio,
            descrizione : descriziones,
            descrizione_lunga : descrizione_lungas,
            index:index,
            x:x,
            y:y
        });
        this.servizi_selezionati_desktop[0].lineaApparte = classe;
    }
```

this update the "servizi_selezionati" data defined in vue

**THE PROBLEM**
now i'm trying to triggering "AddServizi" method using another method in vue instance, that is called from a child component:

CHILD COMPONENT METHOD...

```
        this.$emit('centramappa',{nomeServizio,x,y,selected,classe,index,descrizione,descrizione_lunga});
    }
```

..CALLED IN HTML

```
                    <lista-servizi-gialla 
                :servizi="modello"
                :extdesktop="servizi_selezionati_desktop[0].lineaApparte" 
                v-on:centramappa="mappaCenter($event)" 
                v-on:linebigger="inebigger($event)"
                v-on:cambiacolore="evidenziaLineaDiversa($event)"
                >
                </lista-servizi-gialla>
```

..MAIN JS

```
mappaCenter : function({nomeServizio,x,y,selected,classe,index,descrizione,descrizione_lunga}){
  this.AddServizi(selected,colore,nomeServizio,descrizione,descrizione_lunga,index,x,y);
}
```

mappacenter call AddServizi, but this time the method don't update the model... 
does anybody know why? thank you in advance

Comment: Got a jsfiddle?

Comment: too long to replicate intrely

Comment: You don't need to replicate your entire UI, just a small representation of the issue. For small, simple bugs, code snippets can be enough but with complex interactions like this you can't really expect someone to dive into troubleshooting if you can't at least make a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that when you use something like `this.servizi_selezionati_desktop[0].lineaApparte = classe;`, you're circumventing the vue reactivity.

you should use `Vue.set(this.servizi_selezionati_desktop[0], lineaApparte, classe)`

read more here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: good suggest but seems not working... plus when the function is triggered by on click the console return me ReferenceError: lineaApparte is not defined